# How to completely remove Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from a windows 7 dualboot?

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from a USB flash-drive, it was very fine. But now I'm missing my games that I had on Windows 7.
 My question is: how do I remove Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from my Windows 7 laptop:)

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Delete the Ubuntu partitions (possibly restore the Windows bootloader)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove grub using [this post](http://blog.eukhost.com/webhosting/howto-remove-grub-loader-and-restore-windows-7-and-vista-bootloader/).

After it you will be able to boot only windows
Delete Ubuntu partition by right click on `my computer` . `choose Manage` > `disk management` > select Ubuntu partition > `delete` using right click.

Comment: But witch disk is the ubuntu disk??

Comment: Check size of linux partition, It will 5GB less in windows

Comment: Link-only answers......give dead links :/